# Tzdata.EtsHolder terminating with {:error, :cannot_create_table}

Tags: elixir

When I start my server with this command:

```
mix phx.server
```

I get this error message:

```
pid=<0.2324.0> error_logger=format [error] GenServer Tzdata.EtsHolder terminating
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :cannot_create_table}
    (tzdata) lib/tzdata/ets_holder.ex:59: Tzdata.EtsHolder.load_ets_table/1
    (tzdata) lib/tzdata/ets_holder.ex:52: Tzdata.EtsHolder.load_release/0
    (tzdata) lib/tzdata/ets_holder.ex:23: Tzdata.EtsHolder.handle_cast/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:637: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:711: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:"$gen_cast", :new_release_has_been_downloaded}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This is [a known problem](https://github.com/lau/tzdata/issues/79) in earlier tzdata versions.  Upgrade tzdata to 0.5.20 to get rid of this error.